# Xfce Session: Asks for my password as I use Software Center

Tags: software-center, xfce

As I attempt to install GIMP via the Software Center, I get an issue prompting for my password that is usual when installing things from the Center. But my password does not work with this and I know for a fact what my password is.

Anyone have any experience or knowledge to why this is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu, then you should know the password.

Comment: You clearly didn't get what I was saying, I said I know my password. It works fine on any other DE and I've tested it just now. I've always kept it the same and it does not work on the session.

Comment: From past Xubuntu version I remember issue with gksu and software center. Which version are you running?

Comment: Ah it does not matter I've given up it was too much fuss to deal with and chosen to go back with Gnome Flashback.

Answer (score 0):

Software center needs root privileges to install packages.  There are two ways it can get root privileges.  If your account is setup for sudo access it will likely ask for your password.  If your account is not setup for sudo access it will ask for the root password, in this case it may ask for the administrative accounts password.

Comment: Yeah I know the password it works fine it only occurs on the XFCE Session. (I'm not new to Ubuntu)